# How to add a progress bar to a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a web app using Laravel and React. I want to implement a progress bar in the same style as Youtube for example, a top linear bar displaying the progress of the page loading. How to do so ?

I already found some pre-configured progressbar but don't know how to "link" them with all my pages.

My index.js file where all my pages :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import User from './User';
import HeaderMenu from './components/HeaderMenu';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import Widget1 from './components/Widget1';
import Patient from './pages/patients';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { HandleProgressBar } from "./components/ProgressBar";
 



class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    const { cookies } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
        <HandleProgressBar />
          <Menu /> 
          <HeaderMenu />  
          
            <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/"  component={User}>
                <User />
            </Route>

            <Route path='/patients' component={Patient}>
                <Patient />
            </Route> 
          </Switch> 
          
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
    
}
}

export default Index;

// DOM element
if (document.getElementById('index')) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('index'));
}
```

HandleProgressBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TopBarProgress from "react-topbar-progress-indicator";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


TopBarProgress.config({
  barColors: {
    "0": "#5f6875",
    "0.5": "#4a535f",
    "1.0": "#373d45",
  },
    shadowBlur: 0,
    barThickness: 2
});


export class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

  render() {
        
    const { progressBarStatus } = this.props;
        
    if(progressBarStatus === 'OPEN') {
      return(<TopBarProgress />)
    } else {
      return('');
    }
  }
}

//redux container component
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return({
    progressBarStatus: state.ui.progressBarStatus
  });
};

export const HandleProgressBar = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(ProgressBar);

export default HandleProgressBar;
```

Comment: Can you share the component, i see you're displaying in your app, but where is the css and jsx structure.

Comment: Which component ?

Comment: the HandleProgressBar component, does it have a method to trigger the animation?

Comment: I added it it my initial post. I tried following this tutorial https://rossbulat.medium.com/implementing-a-react-progress-bar-with-redux-4bc2a35c99ce but all I have is a blank page with the following error `The above error occurred in the <ConnectFunction> component:
    in ConnectFunction (created by Index)`  and `Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ProgressBar)"`